# Drracket lists adding only numbers while ignoring other data types

Tags: racket

Hello I need to create a function that consumes a list that sums up only numbers within the list and ignores any other type of data (strings etc)

Example (adding-only-numbers (cons 5 (cons "b" ( cons 2 (cons "whatsup" empty)))))
should come out to (cons 7 (cons "b" (cons "whatsup" empty)))

Keeping all the strings or other data types in order while collecting the numbers and adding them all up.

If there are no numbers, and only strings then it should be 0 at the front

Example (adding-only-numbers (cons "eb" (cons "b" ( cons (make posn 5 0) (cons "whatsup" empty)))))
should come out to (cons 0 (cons "eb" (cons "b" ( cons (make posn 5 0) (cons "whatsup" empty)))))

your help is much appreciated!

Comment: If an answer helps you out, you should choose it as the correct answer.

Comment: this seems like a typical homework question... hopefully you're not using stackoverflow to do your work for you. i'd suggest that you show your attempt at this. think about using a recursive algorithm. also, consider putting this on the computer science stack exchange as an algorithmic question.

Comment: im not sure why foldr filter etc is not defined in my racket... I have version 5.3.3 was I supposed to define them as a helper function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this smells a little like homework, I'll set you on the right track:

```
#!/usr/bin/racket
#lang racket

(define (sum lst)
  (foldl (lambda (num sum)
           (if (number? num) (+ sum num) sum))
         0
         lst))

(sum '(1 2 "hello"))
```

So this will return the summation of a flat list... Should be one more simple step to push this to the front of the list.

Note that the [`foldl`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket/private/list..rkt%29._foldl%29%29) function takes a function to apply for each element, the starting value and the list.

Comment: hey, I'm not sure why foldr is not defined in Drracket, nor is foldl, is there any other type I could use?

Comment: Well you could create it yourself, possibly using `map`